# Unknown arg `email` in where.email for type UserWhereUniqueInput. GraphQL | NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I've been testing GraphQL for a few days now and I'm doing the authentication management (by following [this tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/6-authentication/)). I'm currently blocked with the following error:

```
Unknown arg `email` in where.email for type UserWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `id`?
```

When I make the following request:

```
mutation {
  login(email: "contact@floriankamps.fr", password: "Test123") {
    token
    user {
      email
      links {
        url
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my login resolver:

```
let login = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
    const user = await context.prisma.user.findUnique({ 
        where: {
            email: args.email 
        } 
    });
    if (!user)
        throw new Error('No such user found');

    const valid = await bcrypt.compare(args.password, user.password);
    if (!valid)
        throw new Error('Invalid password');
    
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, APP_SECRET);

    return {
        token,
        user
    }
}
```

And my GraphQL schema:

```
type Mutation {
    post(url: String!, description: String!): Link!
    updateLink(id: Int!, url: String, description: String): Link
    deleteLink(id: Int!): Link
    signup(email: String!, password: String!, name: String!): AuthPayload
    login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload
}
```

I don't really see where it could get in the way...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so after a long investigation, I've found the solution. The problem didn't come from GraphQL but from Prisma.
To add an email field to the User model, we need to define it the @unique directive like this:

```
model User {
  id  Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  email String @unique
  password  String
  links Link[]
}
```

Solution was initially posted here:
https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql/issues/661#issuecomment-401372966

Comment: Thanks. You'll also need to do another prisma migration: `npx prisma migrate dev --name "emailunique"` or completely delete your prisma DB (delete all files from prisma folder except for `schema.prisma`) if you had more users created.

Comment: If you are using findUnique() method then as the function name suggests you are querying your database using some Unique field; so you need to give a unique field as condition in `findUnique` function as well. And as you were getting that error then that means you didn't declare your email field as Unique in your Schema. So thats the reason why making email Field `unique` solved your error.